# SQL replace @lt and @gt with < and >

Tags: sql, xml

I wanted to print @file but it was truncated due to size. So I choose to use:

```
SELECT CAST('<root><![CDATA[' + @file + ']]></root>' AS XML)
```

which gives me all my data but I need to replace the &lt and &gt with the < and >. If I try to use

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST('<root><![CDATA[' + @file + ']]></root>' AS XML),'&lt','<')
```

I get the error message: Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

If I try

```
SET @file = CAST('<root><![CDATA[' + @file + ']]></root>' AS XML)
```

print REPLACE(@file,'&lt','<')

I get the error message: Implicit conversion from data type xml to varchar(max) is not allowed.

If I use

```
SET @file = convert(varchar(max),CAST('<root><![CDATA[' + @file + ']]></root>' AS XML))
```

print REPLACE(REPLACE(@file,'<','<'),'>','>')

It looks good but my data is truncated.

What can I do?

Comment: truncated *where*? Many *developer* client tools will truncate data for display, but all of the data is available for any consuming *application* or *reporting tool*. (Although you should stick to returning the data via `SELECT` rather than `PRINT`)

Comment: the returned data is truncated as viewed in SSMS or copied and pasted into a text app

Comment: What is the content of `@file`? it would help to set up a working test scenario with a small *mockup* and show what you are trying to achieve. Do you really need the `CDATA` section? And please tag your question with the appropriate RDBMS (vendor and version). The tag `sql` is not enough... From your comment with *SSMS* I assume, this is SQL-Server. SSMS can be configured to show XML data unlimited. Go into the query options and look into the "grid" section. You'll have to re-open your query after changing this.